# How to Plot with Label from scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

How can I plot a bunch of 2-D points X (say, using matplotlib) with color labels from scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage(X, method="single") (say, k = 3)?

Comment: I kinda figured it out myself. fcluster from scipy.cluster.hierarchy will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fcluster from scipy.cluster.hierarchy will do.